# bash compute average return bad answer

Tags: bash, echo, average

I have a script with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mark=10+10  
nb=2

echo $mark  
echo $(($mark/$nb))
```

I don't understand why the second echo return 15.

Comment: should be `echo $((mark/nb))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the precendence of operators, and because `mark` is not *evaluated* itself (in a *math*-sense of evaulation).

`echo $(($mark/$nb))` is first replace to `$((10+10/2))` which is then evaluated to `10+5` which is `5`.

There are numerous solutions to the problem, e.g:

```
echo $((mark/nb)
echo $((($mark)/$nb))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

mark=$((10+10))
nb=2

echo $mark  
echo $(($mark/$nb))
```

The reason is that when assigning 10+10 no result is calculated. Instead 10+10/$nb is executed in the last line. And the result is 15 of course.